# HTML coding with page caching?

Tags: html5, html-files

Okay so I wanted to make a HTML webpage and so I created one. Now the page loads stuff from my PC and some cache files are made in the cache folder which have some same size as that of the files loaded. Now the same cache can be loaded for the same window session, but if I close the window copy the cache to another location and delete all cache and then paste it back there, can I make the website to load that cache? I tried this but failed as the website creates new cache for the page. I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: Most browsers keep a directory file that lists the pages in the cache. To copy a cache, you will need to copy ALL the files in the cache. This may further depend on the browser you are using. Please add more information to your post.

Comment: This is also going to be browser specific, since the cache implementation is going to be different between browsers.  Which browser are you wanting to work with?

Answer (score 1):

Some web-based games use an [image pack](http://www.pardus.at/index.php?section=faq_technical) (referenced near the bottom of the page).  This serves multiple purposes:

- Reduced server traffic
- Reduced client traffic
- Increased game responsiveness (because it only sends the text components)

From the link,

> Download an image pack and unzip all files into a folder on your local computer. Then set the image path from "online" to "file://" and enter the directory you have chosen in your Account Settings screen.
>   When playing the game, your system will now refrain from downloading images and css files from the Pardus server, but will use them from your local computer. This way the game can be sped up, and you are even able to completely customize the images and styles shown to you.